# Check MongoDB Status with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

How do I check, if the connection to the MongoDB is active (without using the actuator project) if just a `MongoRepository` is used, which hides the connection?

Comment: if you have implemented something with below suggestion , feel free to share code so that others can use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mongodb connection is inactive then spring boot application will throw errors which can be checked in logs.

Ideally actuator project is best way to check the status.

You can also check the status by creating your own controller method lets say ping and in implementation write some operation like MongoRepository.findAll() if it returns positive value it is in active state.